# sizeof(); returns double the value that of specified array in embedded C

Tags: c, sizeof

**[image of an executed code in keil]**

[image]

I've written above code to move an array( msg[ ] ) to Port 0(I'm using Keil µvision), in which 'unsigned int y' gets the size of the array and displays it to Port 1(Port-1 output is shown in the image, whereas Port-0 output is not)

Question:

1. Why am I getting double the value of the specified array?

Comment: Post code as text to improve clarity.

Comment: I've wanted to show output of port with the code

Comment: You may need `sizeof(msg)/sizeof(msg[0])`.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh : But how is the output port relevant to teh size of the array.  You have not even specified the size you are getting - I would _expect_  on an 8051 platform - you should also specify your platform - I have inferred 8051 from the header file included, if it were not for that I'd have assumed ARM since that is Keil's primary product since there were acquired by ARM.  `sizeof` an array is not the same as the number of elements.  Your expression `sizeof(msg)/2` is ill advised - better `sizeof(msg)/sizeof(*msg)` which will be portable regardless of the platform.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh ; Ah - I see that you are using the port to "display" the size -  You could have used a debugger watchpoint or just said that `y == 8` - we'd have believed you.

Answer (score 2):

Your message is not at all clear, but I believe you are getting 8, when you expect 4.

`sizeof()` returns the number of BYTES in a variable.
If `unsigned int` is 2-bytes on this platform, then an array of 4 ints has a size of 8 bytes.